# emacs forward and back keys

Tags: emacs

Am i unusual or are the emacs forward and back keys the wrong way round?

I constantly hit C-b for forward and C-f for backward because b is forward of f and f is back of b as laid out on the (qwerty) keyboard (at least thats my logic)

C-n and C-p cause no such problems as they are intuitively the right way round, e.g. p is 'up' from n

likewise with C-a and C-e

its nice to have the letter mean something, e.g. f for forward and b for back but my brain prefers actual position over the right initial

does anyone else have this issue?

as an aside how do dvorak users cope?

should i swap the key bindings round or does that way madness lie?

(possibly part of the problem is I have only just started weaning myself of the arrow keys using no-easy-keys.el)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me answer quickly before the famed SO content nazis delet your question as too open-ended. Emacs keybinding on standard 104 key PC keyboard is a disaster. I personally never confused C-f and C-b, but I did get strained pinkies from pressing Ctrl all the time [until I redefined Caps Lock as Ctrl](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/MovingTheCtrlKey). Since then, by miracle, Emacs became the most comfortable piece of software on my machine. But back to your original question, I think I never had problems confusing C-b because it's simply hard to reach. Nevertheless, as much as I love Emacs, I must admit that *vi* rocks for using h, j, k, l keys for, respectively, back, down, up, and forward. I've heard there was a plugin named 'vile' for Emacs, but I never tried it. [That might be of help to you](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ViKeys).

Comment: i already have the 'vital' caps as ctrl - very interesting comment about the vi key-bindings - i assume vim is similar and i think there is a vim mode for emacs, i'm not sure i have it in me to leave emacs for vim based on the location of two key-bindings... (i also thought this would be closed but hoped someone like yourself would answer quickly as its really bugging me)

Comment: @Hiett: I'm not using a vi/vim mode but I'm using custom-made shortcuts to "move the cursor", select, etc.  I'm using a keyboard which has no arrow keys and which has CTRL where it should be (an Happy Hacking Pro 2 keyboard).  I'm using i,j,k,l to move the cursor, mimicking the 'inverted T' arrows keys cluster.  I'm also mapping *ctl-x-map* to CTRL-, so that I can use "CTRL+," instead of "CTRL+x" because if you hit CTRL with your left pinky you then realize that "CTRL+x" doesn't make any sense at all.  Yup, the default Emacs keybindings are terribly bad... But Emacs is entirely configurable.

Answer (score 2):

If you are willing to move away from the defaults, you may want to check out Xah Lee's ErgoEmacs bindings.

http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/ergonomic_emacs_keybinding.html